# Unreal Engine is exiting due to D3D device being lost

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I was trying to code with unreal engine 4 (version 4.24.2), but I don't know why, all of a sudden this happen and since then I couldn't do nothing no matter what the version or projects this keeping happening and I don't know what is it or how to fix it

output log error here:
[image: output log error here]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but it was fixed once I updated to the latest Intel graphics driver.

1. Check your display driver version. 
   (In my case, I used gtx1060 and intel graphics630, and only intel driver was not lastet version)
2. Visit https://downloadcenter.intel.com and update your drivers

Comment: Please explain further how to do this, and what you did.